# How to break label in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have one label which is taking value from database.And the value of label is more than 20 lines.

While displaying that label in pdf ,if label is very big then it is rendering on second page and my first page is half blank.

so I want to break that label on two pages so it will start on first page only and then it will break and then it will render  on second page.What can i do for that?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, determining where to put page breaks on the fly is a weak point of SSRS.

Perhaps you could break up the long text into multiple rows in the data source (splitting on spaces between words).  This would result in funny looking breaks in the output as you won't know for sure where the break will appear in a line on the printed report.

If the text has reasonably sized paragraphs, you could parse it out that way instead using line breaks.